# ListView customize first cell

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Can I have a `ListView` where I can customize the first cell, and then repeat the other cells with some other custom view. Any suggestions to set manually the first row and then set adapter for other cells in different style. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add header to your `ListView`. Use [`addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) method. If header doesn't fits your needs, read [this nice explanation](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) how to apply different layouts to different list items.

Comment: perfect explanation i used getView method and position to get my work done. Thanks a ton